# How do I force timeouts in Jest to test timeout errors?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs

We have a function in our React project to fetch a list of stores. If the fetch takes longer than 10 seconds we abort the request and show an error.

```
const controller = new AbortController();
const getTimeout = setTimeout(() => controller.abort(), 10000);

const fetchStores = storeId => (
    ourFetchStoresFunction(`http://my-api/${storeId}`, {
        headers: { 'x-block': 'local-stores' },
        signal: controller.signal
    })
    .then((results) => {
        clearTimeout(getTimeout);
        return results
    })
    .catch((err) => { throw err; })
);
```

Here is the basic test for the `fetchStores` function:

```
it('fetchStores should return a stores array', () => {
    storesAPI.fetchStores(MOCK_STORES)
    .then((stores) => {
        expect(Array.isArray(stores)).toBe(true);
     })
    .catch();
});
```

How do I mock this timeout in Jest?

using setTimeout in the `.then` block while calling that method did not work. Additionally, I would rather NOT have to wait 10 seconds during the test. I looked up `jest.useFakeTimers` but got nowhere.

Comment: I could test global timers, read here: https://jestjs.io/docs/timer-mocks

You can use jest spyOn function. 
For example: 

let timeoutSpy:; 

beforeEach(() => {
timeoutSpy = jest.spyOn(global, 'setTimeout');
});

afterEach(() => {
 jest.restoreAllMocks();
})

Then in your test, you can expect(tymepoutSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

Something like this should work, worked in my case.

Comment: @TigranPetrosyan Could you put this in an answer so I can accept it if it works for me?

Comment: And how do you prevent the fetch from completing before 10 seconds?

Comment: I added it as an answer. Basically, you need to mock everything and simulate the things. jest.spyOn is super powerful.

Answer (score 0):

I could test global timers, read here: jestjs.io/docs/timer-mocks You can use jest spyOn function. For example:

> ```
> let timeoutSpy; 
> beforeEach(() => { 
>   timeoutSpy = jest.spyOn(global, 'setTimeout'); 
> }); 
> afterEach(() => { 
>  jest.restoreAllMocks(); 
> })
> ```

Then in your test, you can expect(tymepoutSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1); Something like this should work, worked in my case.

In your case, you can mock about controller too, again using jest.spyOn, could be something like this:

> let abortSpy;

In the same beforeEach you can set it:

> `abortSpy = jest.spyOn(AbortController.prototype, 'abort');`

And I suppose ourFetchStoresFunction function is similar to fetch?

And finally, you can mock fetch function, so it takes lots f time to load, it can be done in this way:

```
> global.fetch = jest.fn(() =>   Promise.resolve({ // set some time })
> );
```

Comment: is there no way to do this without delaying the test for the length of the timeout?

Comment: so there are 2 cases: if during 10 seconds you get response back, abort controller does not trigger. If there is a delay, it triggers. 
This is your logic. 
If you want abort controller trigger before we get back the response(lets say component was not mounted, and we dont need API call later), you can return a function in your useEffect and call abort there. 

I hope I understood you correctly.

Comment: Thanks, but what I mean is that we don't want the test to actually wait 10 seconds as this will bloat our test suite. I was wondering if there was a way to mock a timeout, and tell jest "Hey, 15 seconds have passed", and hopefully this would trigger the timeout error without actually waiting 15 seconds.